# Java - SQL Exception column doesn't have default value

Tags: java, sql

I've got this prepared statement: (I do not want to insert data into column_1)

```
pstmt = artclSlctCon.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `temp_articles` (`title`, `author`, `author_id`, `type`, `wfurl`, `intro`, `intro_image`, `main_image`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

With the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'content_1' doesn't have a default value
```

My database looks like this:

[image]
There are lots of image and content columns (17 of each).

Is there anyway to keep the default value of the `image_n` and `content_n` columns `none`?

PhpMyAdmin says:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns don't have a default value and don't support `NULL` values, so it is impossible to insert data in it if you don't provide any value (as you're currently doing). Define a valid default value for these columns or make it support `NULL` values.

Comment: Yep, but reword the first sentence because it's a bit confusing. It's easy to insert data if you supply a value for those columns as well.

Comment: @Crizly: what he's saying is that if you want to skip adding data for column 1 when inserting a row, column 1 must either be able to accept `null` or have a default value. If you don't want to insert a value for column 1 and you don't want column 1 to have a default value, then it must accept `null`. `null` means exactly that (no value was added and there was no default value).

Comment: How do you make it support null? - Atm the code is set up to ignore blank columns in the application, it'd be a pita to rewrite the code, if there is anyway i can set the text/blob columns to something (anything) by default (out of the java code) that would be great - but if not i'll have to add it onto the java code

Comment: @Crizly: When creating the table, don't include the `NOT NULL` modifier for the column. If that GUI you're supports editing the table structure, maybe clicking/double-clicking on the "no" in the "Null" column will change it as well.

Comment: Anyone familiar with PHPMyadmin who can tell him how to change the table to accept nulls for that column?

Comment: I'll try recreate the table without NOT NULL (will take me a few mins to see if it works)

Comment: @Crizly: Yes. :) Any code using it must account for the possibility that no value was assigned.

Comment: hmm should be ok for this purpose - there will never be more than 17 of the 34 areas filled

Comment: @Crizly usually, blob fields should allow `null` values since they're used to store large content such as big chunks of text or files like images.